# Perl simple regex is boggling my mind

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, match

I have a variable $message that when i print produces.

```
 Date:   Wed Jun 26 18:15:11

some message test

[tug=123
    [rug testing one]


the boy fell on the rug

#update]
```

the text may alter, but this format stays constant

```
(random characters)  [tug=(possible number)   
  [(possible text1)] (sometext2) #(possible text3)]
```

how can i grab (possible number), (possible text1), (sometext2) and (possible text3)

I have tried something to grab at least something, but fail with no cigar

```
 if( $message =~ /.*\[tug\s*\[(.*)\]/g){
    my $grab = $1;
  }
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from as it looks like you have multiple newline chars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern to extract your datas:

```
$str =~ /^(?>[^[]++|\[(?!tug=))+\[tug=(\d*+)\s*+\[([^]]*+)]\s*+([^#]+?)\s*+#([^]]*+)]$/;
print "\n".$1."\n".$2."\n".$3."\n".$4;
```

The idea is to avoid the dot.

Notices:

I assume here that when there is no *possible text1* there are still square brackets.

I have choosen to strip white characters after *sometext2*, it's the reason why i use a lazy quantifier (`+?`). If you want preserve them just replace `([^#]+?)\s*+` by `([^#]++)`

Comment: yea i guess the dot is evil eh?

Comment: @YusufAli: no, but i have made the choice to use restrictive character classes instead of the dot to be more descriptive. You could deal with the dot too using the s modifier as depesz suggests it.